# Is point to point connection is more secure than Mule API lead connectivity (SAPI Layer Integration)?

Tags: api, mule, integration, mulesoft, saas

As we know mule api led connectivity better than  the legacy point to point connection where multiple API integration is required.

As we know point to point connection uses dedicated hardware channel and layer 2 protocol to communicate between to system.

My question is in terms of security regardless of cost is Point to Point communication is more beneficial ?

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "point to point connection uses dedicated hardware channel and layer 2 protocol to communicate between to system"

Comment: When you say point to point communication (in context of API LED integration related topic)  it means that two systems are talking directly to each other, it does not require any hardware connection AFAIK. I think you are mixing some other concept here.

Comment: What I am trying to say here is that point to point communication was used earlier to communicate with the legacy 3rd part service , e.g with Main frame service.Now we are using in ESB (System API Layer - SAPI layer to communicate with 3rd party.My Question is that is older Point to Point System had some better security advantage?

Comment: That depends a LOT on the implementation of both the old and new architecture. But if you assume best practices are followed in both architecture, the one that has a dedicated hardware to communicate will almost always be more secure **WHEN COMPARED** TO NETWORK BASED communication. But that does not mean that network based communication is insecure in any way.